# When testing my code, using cout for my class operator results in an operator error

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I am receiving this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:36: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘void’)
   14 |     std::cout << "Date format 1: " << myDate.dateFormat_1();
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |               |                                          |
      |               std::basic_ostream<char>                   void
```

I am unsure on how to fix this. I am new to c++, currently in a master c++ course, and creating the class systems has been confusing time. The member functions dateFormat_2 and 3 have not resulted in any issues nor prompt errors within the compiler so I am somewhat sure they are correct. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Date.h"

int main()
{
    int d;
    int m;
    int y;
    std::cout << "Input three integers for day, month, year: ";
    std::cin << d << m << y;
    Date myDate
    std::cout << "\nDay: " << myDate.getDay() << "\nMonth: " << myDate.getMonth() << "\nYear: " << myDate.getYear() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Date format 1: " << myDate.dateFormat_1() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Date format 2: " << myDate.dateFormat_2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Date format 3: " << myDate.dateFormat_3() << std::endl;
}
```

this is my header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Date
{
    public:
    Date(int d, int m, int y)
    {
        day = d;
        month = m;
        year = y;
    }
    void setDay(int d)
    {
        day = d;
    }
    int getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }
    void setMonth(int m)
    {
        month = m;
    }
    int getMonth()
    {
        return month;
    }
    void setYear(int y)
    {
        year = y;
    }
    int getYear()
    {
        return year;
    }
    void dateFormat_1()
    const{
        std::cout << day << "/" << month << "/" << year;
    }
    void dateFormat_2()
    const{
       std::string day_s;
        std::string month_s;
        if(day<10)
        {
            day_s = '0' + std::to_string(day);
        }
        else
        {
            day_s = day;
        }
        if(month<10)
        {
            month_s = '0' + std::to_string(month);
        }
        else
        {
            month_s = month;
        }
        std::cout << day_s << "/" << month_s << "/" << year;
    }
    
    void dateFormat_3()
    {
        std::string day_s;
        std::string month_s;
        if(day<10)
        {
            day_s = '0' + std::to_string(day);
        }
        else day_s = day;
        
        if(month<10)
        {
            month_s = '0' + std::to_string(month);
        }
        else month_s = month;
        
        std::cout << year << month_s << day_s;
    }
    
    private:
    int day, month, year;
};
```

Comment: Your `dateFormat_*` functions don't return anything, so there is nothing to print.

Comment: Can you use C++20? If so you should use std::format. `std::cout << std::format("{:%d:%m:%Y_%H%M}", std::chrono::system_clock::now());`;. In any case do not write your own date/time classes but use the <chrono> header. Time is a notoriously difficult thing to get right

Comment: This seems to be a somewhat common misunderstanding how output works. Can you please explain your own thoughts about the "output" and how you think it works?

Comment: *"I am unsure on how to fix this."* -- The fix depends on what your code is supposed to do. In the absence of functional requirements, deleting the problematic lines from `main` is a valid fix...

Comment: Seems like the common newbie confusion between *return* and *print*. These mean different things, although which the OP is trying to do is not clear.

Comment: No one has yet commented on this line from the OP: `std::cin << d << m << y;`. It uses `<<`, when it should use `>>`.

Comment: @nicocormier – What does this function do? `std::string zero_fill(int const n) { return (n < 10 ? "0" : "") + std::to_string(n); }` How could it be used to turn functions `dateFormat_2` and `dateFormat_3` into one-liners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we make it simpler, you're essentially doing

```
std::cout << myDate.dateFormat_1();
```

This calls the function `myDate.dateFormat_1()` and will attempt to output the value it returns. But `myDate.dateFormat_1()` doesn't return anything, so you get the error.

What you want is just a plain function call:

```
std::cout << "Date format 1: ";  // Output heder text
myDate.dateFormat_1();           // Call function, and it will write its own output
std::cout << '\n';               // Output a trailing newline
```

Similarly with the other two functions, call them separately.

Answer (score 1):

`Some programmer dude` gave you a quick fix which is fine, but IMO problem you should think about changing API of your `Date`.

Solution depends on skill level, that is why `Some programmer dude` provided minimal solution, but I'd like to move you one step forward, by introducing `std::string` as a return type and C++20 [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) which is more handy and easy to use:

```cpp
class Date {
....
    std::string dateFormat_1() const
    {
        return std::format("{}/{}/{}", day, month, year);
    }

    std::string dateFormat_2() const
    {
        return std::format("{:02}/{:02}/{:02}", day, month, year);
    }

    std::string dateFormat_3()
    {
        return std::format("{:02}/{:02}/{:02}", year, month, day);
    }
....
};
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/41za4sq7W) (I've fixed more mistakes in your code to make it compile).

This can be also achieved in old C++ standard by [using `std::ostringstream`](https://godbolt.org/z/1eeq1sarT), but its API is more complex and harder to use.

Depending on compiler (and it is version) you are using you have enable C++20 it respective way.